# launch jobs using a dynamically created xml configuration using spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I'm wondering if I can do the following using spring batch (just trying it out as it seems to suit our requirements).

We want to save off a XML configuration based on user requests (essentially a list of jobs/steps/flows). At some point in the future, we would like to use this XML to launch the jobs. The flow for the jobs would be determined at the time it is created/modified. The execution of jobs only would need to read the XML and then launch all the jobs. I couldn't find something that would allow us to pass the XML to jobLauncher (or something similar).

Also, is there a way to serialize a set of jobs to XML so we can use that during the part where we save the configuration?

Thank you for your help in advance. All help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are some support for updaloading xml files with jobs in [Spring Batch Admin](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch-admin/reference/jobs.html)